# get coordinates of the first alphabet extracted during OCR in winform application in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ocr

is there any way or any DLL by which i can get location or coordinates of the first letter or alphabet found using OCR in windows form application C# without performing OCR on the whole document?

As i have used Aspose and tesseract Dll to perform OCR on image.it takes time while extracting text as it reads all the text but i want to just read the first word and get the coordinate of the first letter extracted. i have to implement it in windows form application using C#. please help.
Thanks in advance.!

Comment: use Emgu.CV....

Comment: @NicoRiff thanks , but can you tell me how? as i am looking documents on official and related sites, i am unable to figure out how to get location,co-ordinates of first letter of the page.

For Eg. i am having a document which has  page number as the top most item , so i want to get the location of the page number, without going through whole OCR process of page.

Comment: You can try using a segmentation algorithm to try to find zones of text and then pick the top-most zone of text and just perform OCR on those specific bounds. Not sure if Tesseract offers that functionality however. If this is something you think will work, let me know and I can provide some sample code as an answer on how to achieve this.

Comment: @hcham1 please provide sample code, let see if they work or not

Comment: I answered but please be aware the answer references a paid SDK. Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for and I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Just as a disclaimer this answer is about a paid software toolkit and I work for the company.**

You can check out the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/) which has the segmentation algorithm that I mentioned in my comment to zone the document and then find the top-left most zone of text and perform OCR on those bounds.

I wrote a console application to show an example of how to achieve this using the LEADTOOLS OCR NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Ocr/

```
using Leadtools;
using Leadtools.Codecs;
using Leadtools.ImageProcessing.Core;
using Leadtools.Ocr;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace FindFirstZone
{
    class Program
    {
        static IOcrEngine ocrEngine;
        static RasterCodecs codecs;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Initialize();
            var image = codecs.Load(@"randomtext.png");
            LeadRect rect = FindFirstZone(image);
            DoOcr(image, rect);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Initialize()
        {
            RasterSupport.SetLicense(@"C:\LEADTOOLS 20\Common\License\LEADTOOLS.LIC",
                System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\LEADTOOLS 20\Common\License\LEADTOOLS.LIC.KEY"));

            codecs = new RasterCodecs();

            ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD, false);
            ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, null);
        }

        static LeadRect FindFirstZone(RasterImage img)
        {
            AutoZoningCommand autoZoningCommand = new AutoZoningCommand(
                AutoZoningOptions.DetectAccurateZones |
                AutoZoningOptions.DetectText |
                AutoZoningOptions.DontAllowOverlap);
            autoZoningCommand.Run(img);

            if (autoZoningCommand.Zones != null && autoZoningCommand.Zones.Count > 0)
            {
                var sortedList = autoZoningCommand.Zones.OrderBy(z => z.Bounds.Top)
                    .ThenBy(z => z.Bounds.Left).ToList();
                return sortedList[0].Bounds;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No Zones");
        }

        static void DoOcr(RasterImage image, LeadRect rect)
        {
            using (var ocrPage = ocrEngine.CreatePage(image, OcrImageSharingMode.None))
            {
                ocrPage.Zones.Add(new OcrZone()
                {
                    Bounds = rect,
                    ZoneType = OcrZoneType.Text,
                });
                ocrPage.Recognize(null);
                Console.WriteLine(ocrPage.GetText(-1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this with some random text I generated [(test image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEDwu.png) and here is the output from this program:

> Fowl it heaven second don't thing won't third cattle from. Had said
>   fill brought evening, a said great him

Comment: is this SDK available for demonstration purpose,i.e without providing any billing details.just for demo

Comment: Yes, there is a free 60 day trial on the website http://www.leadtools.com and all you need is your name and email.